# autocomplete through Array of strings in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, autocomplete, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using [this gist](https://gist.github.com/map7/1347080) to build autocomplete functionality in my Rails app.

I'm saving record in `Shoe` model attribute like below

```
"nike air, nike steam,nike softy ,nike strength"  #comma separated words
```

My controller code is below

```
def shoes
  shoes_list = []
  shoes = Shoe.all

  shoes.each do |shoe|
    shoes_list << shoe.model.split(',')
  end unless shoes.blank?

  if params[:term]
    like = "%".concat(params[:term].concat("%"))
    # shoes = Shoe.where("model like ?", like)
    # **How i make like query to "shoes_list" same like above commented line?**
  else
    shoes = Shoe.all
  end

  list = shoes.map { |u| Hash[id: u.id, label: u.model, model: u.model] }
  render json: list
end
```

How do I render it in json format?

Comment: The [*very first line* of the gist](https://gist.github.com/map7/1347080#file-rails-org-L1) says "autocomplete under Rails 3.1," and you're using it with Rails 4?

Comment: It is working with Rails 4. But now my requirement changed that i want to autocomplete in little more complex way. I will first save multiple comma separated words in Shoe (model attribute).Then on base of all words exists in all rows of shoes table. Then split it all on the base of comma to make it single word and use all these words for autocomplete.

Comment: So you basically want a single CSV string to act as multiple autocomplete values?

Comment: Not multiautocomplete, use it for single autocomplete(for one word)

Comment: No, I meant multiple strings that will hit the same `Shoe` record. For example, if I start typing *nike*, it will show autocomplete suggestions *nike air*, *nike steam*, *nike softy*, *nike strength*... all separate words but all pointing to the same `Shoe` record?

Comment: Yes @gg_s you are right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At last this code works for me.

```
         def shoes
              shoes_list = []
              shoes = Shoe.all
              shoes.each do |shoe|
                shoes_list << shoe.model.split(',')
              end unless shoes.blank?
              shoes_list.flatten!

              if params[:term]
                shoes = shoes_list.grep(Regexp.new( Regexp.escape(params[:term]), "i" ))
              else
                shoes = shoes_list
              end
            list = shoes.map {|u| Hash[id: u, label: u, name: u]}
            render json: list
          end
```

Also see [How get value from array of strings in Ruby 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16899448/how-get-value-from-array-of-strings-in-ruby-2-0)