# How get value from array of strings in Ruby 2.0

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have this array of strings:

```
array = [ "nike air", "nike steam","nike softy" ,"nike strength",
          "smooth sleeper","adidas air","addidas jogar","adidas softy","adidas heels"]
```

I want to extract strings from this as SQL like query.

E.g if user enter word "nike". Then 4 strings should be return as result

```
           "nike air", "nike steam","nike softy" ,"nike strength"
```

E.g if user enter word "adidas". Then 4 strings should be return as result

```
           "adidas air","addidas jogar","adidas softy","adidas heels"
```

Is it possible?

Comment: What code have you written to solve the problem? This is a pretty simple thing to do.

Comment: Not directly related but possibly relevant: [SQL has a `LIKE` predicate](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Where_(SQL)&oldid=555492110#LIKE), which allows you to pretty much do this but at the database layer. It might offer you a more flexible solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
array.grep(query)
```

Returns the array subset that matches the query.

Comment: array.grep('nike') gives be blank array

Comment: Try with Regexp instead of String.

Comment: @Kashiftufail i.e. `/nike/` instead of `'nike'`

Answer (score 7):

Use [`Enumerable#grep`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-grep):

```
matches = array.grep /nike/
```

Add `/i` for case insensitive. To construct a regexp from a string:

```
re = Regexp.new( Regexp.escape(my_str), "i" )
```

Or, if you want your users to be able to use special Regexp queries, just:

```
matches = array.grep /#{my_str}/
```

Comment: @Phrogh   matches = array.grep /nike/ give me accurate result but matches = array.grep /"nike"/  give me nothing.                                 so how  i should execute this code in my controller                        matches = array.grep /"#{params[:term]}"/
 while params[:term] is string value

Comment: Use `array.grep(Regexp.new(Regexp.escape(params[:term])))`

Answer (score 2):

Or you can build your query method by yourself:

```
def func( array )
  array.each_with_object [] do |string, return_array|
    return_array << string if string =~ /nike/
  end
end
```

Comment: Way more work (for both programmer and computer) than is necessary.

Comment: @Phrogz Definitely for programmer--is the implementation of `grep` C-ish? Otherwise wouldn't grep do much the same thing? I can't check at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

```
array = [ "nike air", "nike steam","nike softy" ,"nike strength",
          "smooth sleeper","adidas air","addidas jogar","adidas softy","adidas heels"]
array.select{|i| i.include? "nike"}

# >> ["nike air", "nike steam", "nike softy", "nike strength"]
```

Comment: @louism Perhaps you should explain your answer on the changes and how this approach is the "best" to resolve the OPS problem

Comment: This method is clearer. "Select the words that contain 'nike'" is simple, elegant and more idiomatic Ruby IMHO.